# Verilog Non-Blocking and IF statement mixed

Tags: fpga, verilog

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    clk_counter <= clk_counter + 1;
    if(clk_counter == divider)
       clk_counter <= 0;
end
```

Will the `clk_counter <= clk_counter + 1;` and `if` statement be executed concurrently so the clk_counter evaulation at if statement will be the old one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statements within a `begin/end` block execute sequentially. However, a nonblocking assignment statement evaluates the RHS as it executes and schedules an update to the LHS in a later event region.

If there are multiple updates scheduled to the same variable, last update wins. So this code executes effectively the same as

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if(clk_counter == divider)
       clk_counter <= 0;
    else 
       clk_counter <= clk_counter + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` will be evaluated before any change is made to the `clk_counter` signal because the assignments are non-blocking.

The assignment of 0 to the `clk_counter` signal should take priority over the increment assignment because it happens afterwards.

Putting the increment into an `else` would have equivalent behaviour, whilst being clearer code.